# How to create multiple timer handler in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, timer, handler

- I have to create multiple timer "n" times with handler.
- Which will be stored for a row in my DataGrid.
- For each row there will be a timer that works seperately.

What I thought of looks like:

```
Private Sub CreateTimer()
    Dim tmr As New Timer
    tmr.Interval = 1000 '1 Second
    tmr.Enabled = True
    AddHandler tmr.Tick, AddressOf GlobalTimerTick
End Sub

'A timer tick handler that would work for each timer I add with the sub above
'All timers I created should work seperately
Private Sub GlobalTimerTick(TheTimer as Timer, ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    mynumber = mynumber + 1
    With DataGridView1
        .Rows(n).Cells(4).Value = mynumber " saniye"
    End With
End Sub
```

So how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use `Tag` property to know what timer is associated with which row. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tag(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `Tag` property of Timer would work beautifully in your case. I don't have my IDE currently, but the following snippet should give you the idea.

```
Private Sub CreateTimer()
    Dim tmr As New Timer
    tmr.Interval = 1000 '1 Second
    tmr.Enabled = True
    tmr.Tag = ROW_INDEX
    AddHandler tmr.Tick, AddressOf GlobalTimerTick
End Sub

'A timer tick handler that would work for each timer I add with the sub above
'All timers I created should work seperately
Private Sub GlobalTimerTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    mynumber = sender.Tag
    With DataGridView1
        .Rows(n).Cells(4).Value = mynumber " saniye"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like adding sender.Stop() to this works as well thank you!